# Argument latlong: Got invalid value {} on prisma.createOneSchedule. Provided Json, expected BigInt.?

Tags: typescript, prisma

```
async create(data: Prisma.ScheduleCreateInput) {
    await this.prismaService.schedule.create({ data });
    return RESPONSE_MESSAGE.SCHEDULE_SUCCESS;
  }
```

BigInt is a datatype .so any changes are made to done in create place?. it show the error in console. "provided JOSN excepted bigint".

```
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement()) @map("ez05_invsche_id")
  product   Product? @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  service   Service? @relation(fields: [serviceId], references: [id])
  productId Int      @map("ez05_invsche_prdid")
  serviceId Int      @map("ez05_invsche_ser_id")
  address1  String   @map("ez05_invsche_add1")
  address2  String?  @map("ez05_invsche_add2")
  latlong   BigInt   @map("ez05_invsche_latlong")
  city      String   @map("ez05_invsche_city")
  state     String   @map("ez05_invsche_state")
  country   String   @map("ez05_invsche_cont")
  pincode   Int      @map("ez05_invsche_pc")
  createdAt DateTime @default(now()) @map("ez05_invsche_created_at")
  updatedAt DateTime @default(now()) @map("ez05_invsche_updated_at")
  createdBy String?  @map("ez05_invsche_created_by")
  updatedBy String?  @map("ez05_invsche_updated_by")
```

Comment: Could you share your `schema.prisma` and what you're passing in `data` in the above function?